# Can not derive $\cos (x + y)$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

I am trying to calculate $\cos 11^\circ = \cos(10^\circ + 1^\circ)$, i.e., trying to derive the formula $\cos(x + y)$ using the following drawing:

[image]

Note that I was able to derive the formula $\sin (x + y)$ by using this drawing but I am stuck with $\cos 11^\circ$.

My steps:
$OD = 1^\circ$
$OK = OD\cdot \cos 11^\circ = 1 \cdot \cos 11^\circ = \cos 11^\circ$
But also:
$OK = OF \cdot \cos 10^\circ$
Now we have to find $OF$
$OF = OE - EF = (OD \cdot \cos 1^\circ) - EF = (1 \cdot \cos 1^\circ) - EF = \cos 1^\circ - EF$
So now we have to find $EF$ which is where I am stuck. If I do e.g.
$EF =DF\cdot \sin 10^\circ$ (I think the angle $FDE$ is $10$ degrees because the angles $EFD = KFO$ and both are right angled triangles) leads nowhere because now I have to find $DF$ and it seems impossible based on what I know.
Trying to switch to the triangle $FEN$ (I think that is also the similar to $OME$) also leads to nowhere.
What am I missing here? Please note I don't recall all the possible ways to figure out equal angles so if you mention an approach please be explicit on how that is found.
Also I am interested in the derivation  based on this drawing, not a different approach

Comment: [Proof without words](http://daylateanddollarshort.com/bloog/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/angaddsub.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly got it. You have to use that $DE=1·\sin(1°)$ from the ODE triangle, and also $DE=DF·\cos(10°)$ inside the DEF triangle. Thus
$$
EF=DF·\sin(10°)=\frac{\sin(1°)\sin(10°)}{\cos(10°)}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, since you already proved the sum identity for sines: $$\cos(a+b)=\sin(90^\circ- (a+b))\\
=\sin((90^\circ- a)+(-b))\\
=\sin(90^\circ- a)\cos(-b)+\cos(90^\circ- a)\sin(-b)\\
=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)
.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\overline{OE} = \cos(1^\circ)$.

Therefore 
$\overline{OM} = \cos(10^\circ)\cos(1^\circ)$.

$\overline{ED} = \sin(1^\circ)$.

Also $\angle DEG = 10^\circ.$

Therefore, 
$\overline{MK} = \overline{DG} = \sin(10^\circ)\sin(1^\circ)$.

Finally, 
$\cos(11^\circ) = \overline{OK} = \overline{OM} - \overline{MK}.$

Comment: Ah, this logic is much simpler than mine

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to derive the formula $\ \cos(10+1)=$$\cos(10)\cos(1)-$$\sin(10)\sin(1)\ $, one way of approaching that problem is to write down $\ \cos(10),\cos(1),\sin(10), \sin(1)\ $ and $\ \cos(11)\ $ in terms of any and all ratios of line segments you can find, and then look for ones for which the numerators of one of $\ \cos(10)\ $ and $\ \cos(1)\ $ and one of $\ \sin(10)\ $ and $\ \sin(1)\ $ cancel out with the denominators of the other.  Since the actual values of the angles are immaterial, I'll put $\ a=10\ $ and $\ b=1\ $.  Then you have
\begin{align}
\cos(a+b)&=\frac{OK}{OD}\\
\cos(a)&=\frac{OK}{OF}=\frac{OM}{OE}=\frac{FN}{FE}\\
\cos(b)&=\frac{OE}{OD}\\
\sin(a)&=\frac{KF}{OF}=\frac{ME}{OE}=\frac{EN}{FE}=\frac{DG}{DE}\\
\sin(b)&=\frac{DE}{OD}\ .
\end{align}
Now notice that the numerator of $\ \cos(b)=\frac{OE}{OD}\ $ cancels out with the denominator of $\ \cos(a)=\frac{OM}{OE}\ $, so we get $\ \cos(a)\cos(b)=\frac{OM}{OD}\ $, and the numerator of $\ \sin(b)=\frac{DE}{OD}\ $ cancels out with the denominator of $\ \sin(a)=\frac{DG}{DE}\ $, giving $\ \sin(a)\sin(b)=\frac{DG}{OD}\ $. Therefore
\begin{align}
\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)&=\frac{OM-DG}{OD}\\
&=\frac{OM-KM}{OD}\\
&=\frac{OK}{OD}\\
&=\cos(a+b)\ .
\end{align}

Comment: That is a helpful idea and it seems to me that for it to work we must go backwards from the actual solution right? Otherwise I don't think I would have been able to think the manipulations with cancelling terms

Comment: Yes, it would certainly be much harder to discover the formula itself than it is to discover a proof of it when you already know what it is.  Also, if all you wanted to do is find $\ \cos(11)\ $ given $\ \cos(10)\ $ and $\ \cos(1)\ $,  there are ways of doing that without directly using this formula.  You could use the formula $\ \sin(x)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}\ $, for instance, for $\ x=10\ $ and $\ x=1\ $, calculate $\ \sin(10+1)\ $, then use the frmula $\ \cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}\ $ for $\ x=11\ $ to calculate $\ \cos(11)\ $.